# Receiving same message multiple times via web socket. The older messages are replaced after 3 or 4 new chat messages

Tags: reactjs, redux, websocket, react-redux

I am integrating **web sockets** into React with Django in back-end.

I am able to send messages, and receive the new messages from the back-end.

**The problem** is that after sending 3 or 4 messages, the previous messages are getting replaced by the new messages in the front-end, but all is fine in the back-end, and in fact everything works normally after I refresh.

How to properly update state for situations like this?

#### Edit:

The main problem which I found now is, when I send a chat, the state gets updated multiple times, and its length changes everytime and the screen flutters a lot.

**slice**

```
name: 'chat',
initialState: {
        chatMessages: [],
}

reducers: {
        setChatMessages(state, action) {
            const chatmessages = action.payload;
            return {...state, chatMessages:chatmessages}; 
        },
}
```

**chat**

```
const chatMessagesSelector = useSelector(selectChats);
const chatMessages = chatMessagesSelector?.chatMessages

    chatSocket.onmessage = (e) => {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data)
    var message = {message: data.message, user: data.user,
                    timestamp: data.timestamp};  
    //console.log(message)
    let updatedMessages = [...chatMessages];
    updatedMessages.push(message);
    dispatch(setChatMessages(updatedMessages));
}
```

This is the `chatMessages` object logged above the `updatedMessages`.

```
Array(1)
0: {user: "testuser", message: "check!", timestamp: "2021-03-09T09:15:09.408717+01:00}
length: 1
```

Comment: after every 3 or 4 messages and sometimes for the other user, it replaces all other messages and only shows the current one

Comment: yes..`chatMessages` is from reducer. I will update the question mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code (Approach 1*):

```
chatSocket.onmessage = (e) => {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data)
    var message = {message: data.message, user: data.user, timestamp: data.timestamp};
    let updatedMessages = [...chatMessages];
    updatedMessages.push(message);
    dispatch(setChatMessages(updatedMessages));
```

reads from redux and creates new Array and pushes new element and dispatches the **whole** array.

Instead of that, (Approach 2), you can just send the new **element** to be pushed to redux store by the reducer:

```
chatSocket.onmessage = (e) => {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data)
    var message = {message: data.message, user: data.user, timestamp: data.timestamp};   
    dispatch(setChatMessages(message));
```

And now (for Approach 2) you need to make this change in reducer:

```
reducers: {
   setChatMessages(state, action) {
      return {...state, chatMessages: [...state.chatMessages, action.payload]};}
}
```

You can also do this:

```
reducers: {
   setChatMessages(state, action) {
      state.chatMessages.push(action.payload)
}
```

because :

> Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
> doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the Immer library,
> which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
> immutable state based off those changes

*Approach 1 may be buggy if `chatMessages` in your component is outdated or delayed.

#### Edit:

The real issue seems to be that your event listener is getting registered **multiple times**:

To fix it, you should move it into `useEffect` or `componentDidMount`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  chatSocket.onmessage = (e) => {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data)
    // ...
  }
  return function cleanup() {
    // de-register the socket event
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: Hii thanks for the response. I tried this just now, but now, every message I send is showing more than 4 or 5 times for both users and when I change the reducer, no messages are getting loaded.

Comment: Hi console.log the data, and from the server also it is showing 3 or more times, but getting saved in the db only once,printing out the `receive` in the back-end shows the message only once.

and when I change the reducer, I am not able to see the old messages.

Comment: Try ths [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverlfow-question-14-mar-fwzmz?file=/src/components/message/messageSlice.ts), I demoed how you can just dispatch single "element" and "push" in the slice.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out. but the main problem which I found now is, when I send a chat, the state gets updated multiple times and it's length changes everytime and the screen flutters a lot.

Comment: This is happening with the code I wrote, I would change it to the one you made and will update you regarding the status. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work, it is showing the messages multiple times and only after refresh it shows correctly.

Comment: Its in the front-end, the backend works fine, like the message is only pushed once and only once the data getting saved in the db.

Comment: When I did that, it is showing duplicates

Comment: Ok, but the same is working fine with vanilla js, anyway I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, perfect..now it works! Thanks a lot...:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate new messages with old messages, but you are replacing them:

```js
setChatMessages(state, action) {
  const chatMessages = action.payload;
  return { ...state, chatMessages: state.chatmessages.concat(chatMessages)};
}
```

Be careful and avoid duplicates, if you store same messages locally and then send them back from socket.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I tried this but getting an error `chatMessages is not defined` even though I have initialized it.

Comment: Spotted an error and fixed it in code. `chatMessages` variable from payload was initialize with all lowercase (`chatmessages`)

Comment: I tried it, still it doesn't update it properly as now the chat section is showing everything more than once..like duplicating..is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: As I said, there can be duplicates, if you push your same messages back from socket.  You can either filter them by timestamp, or by id, for example